# In nested class, how can control that the duplicate information is not recorded in a table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a web service that users can send for that information like the following example.

The problem occurs when the information sent in a class is the same. Like a "sampleLine" in code.

How can I control it not to be stored in the duplicate information "sampleLine" table?

```
public class samplePerson
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public sampleCopmany PersonCopmany { get; set; }

    public sampleLine PersonLine { get; set; }
}

public class sampleCopmany
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public sampleLine CopmanyLine { get; set; }
}

public class sampleLine
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class sampleDBContext
{
    private MyDBContext dBContext;

    public sampleDBContext()
    {
        dBContext = new MyDBContext();
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        samplePerson samplePerson = new samplePerson();

        samplePerson.ID = -1;

        samplePerson.Name = "Reza";

        samplePerson.PersonCopmany = new sampleCopmany()
        {
            ID = -1,
            Name = "Test",
            CopmanyLine = new sampleLine()
            {
                ID = -1,
                Name = "line"
            }
        };

        samplePerson.PersonLine = new sampleLine()
        {
            ID = -1,
            Name = "line"
        };

        dBContext.Add(samplePerson);

        dBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to control this item?

Comment: Why don't you simply check if `sampleLine` exists in database before creating it in the relation.

Comment: This was just an example , i use pattern GenericRepository and unit of work for save information

Comment: "samplePerson" is "TEntity" Which is sent in "GenericRepository"

Answer (score 0):

There is not any automatic way in `EF` that handles it for you and you need to manually check for the existence of data before creating it.
If the record exists, then use the existing key and if not then create the record as you have done in your sample code.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question